# How can I fix my Bootstrap 3 RC1 navbar HAML code to work in narrow/mobile views?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, haml, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been using the following HAML code to generate a Bootstrap 2.x.y navbar:

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-inverse
    .navbar-inner
        .container
            %a.brand{:href => '/'} xyz.com
            %ul.nav
                %li
                    %a{:href => '/'}Home
                %li
                    %a{:href => '/blog'}Articles
                %li
                    %a{:href => '/research'}Research
                %li
                    %a{:href => '/contact'}Contact
                %li
                    %a{:href => '/gallery',}Gallery
```

When viewed in a narrow browser window or on a mobile phone, the navbar elements were nicely stacked as shown in the screenshot:

[image: Old navbar view on mobile]

I just tried upgrading my project to Bootstrap 3. I am now using this HAML code for the navbar:

```
.navbar.navbar-fixed-top.navbar-inverse
    .container
        %a.navbar-brand{:href => '/'} xyz.com
        %ul.nav.navbar-nav
            %li
                %a{:href => '/'}Home
            %li
                %a{:href => '/blog'}Articles
            %li
                %a{:href => '/research'}Research
            %li
                %a{:href => '/contact'}Contact
            %li
                %a{:href => '/gallery',}Gallery
```

However, the navbar now does not work as before (see second screenshot):

[image: New, broken navbar]

How can I fix the HAML code to get back to the old behavior using bootstrap 3 RC1?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with HAML, and not the new version of Bootstrap? Also, are you using the correct syntax? One version of your code uses `.navbar-inner` above `.container`, the other has `.navbar-nav` inside `.container`.

Comment: You are right, I was not very precise with my question. Of course the problem is not directly related to HAML, it's just that I am using HAML to generate the HTML.

I tried all kinds of combinations of containers etc., that's why my syntax has changed...

Answer (score 3):

While Bootstrap 3.0 is in RC1, the default version available contains css for a responsive navbar (this may also be true for future versions too)

Line 2922: http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.css contains the media query for min-width of 768px.

You can manually add the css that makes the navbar display items display inline to your code:

```
<style>
.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
.navbar-nav {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
  float: left;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a {
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-nav.pull-right {
  float: right;
  width: auto;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  top: auto;
  left: auto;
  display: none;
}
.nav-collapse.collapse {
  display: block !important;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you include this in your  as described by http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/? I had the same issue w/o this tag after migrating from 2.3

%meta{name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'}